# Expandable Height GridView inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview

i am using Expandableheightgrideview inside Scroll view,

my problem is when i try to add content  in gridview, the content is not expand properly, its displaying 2 scroll bar  when its height is exist(its suppose to be an one common scroll bar for entire page).Bottom of the content is hide to view bottom content in gride view need to scroll down.

i used `exGridView.setExpanded(true);` but no luck

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.ExpandableHeightGridView
            android:id="@+id/result_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:numColumns="1"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp" >
        </com.ExpandableHeightGridView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/start_task_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_gravity="right">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                    android:text="Home"
                    android:textSize="12dip" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html check this link it may be helpgul to you

Answer (score 2):

The Answer is here [Problems with GridView inside ScrollView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264951/problems-with-gridview-inside-scrollview-in-android)

I used ExpandableHeightGridView.java of gitHub and works 
https://gist.github.com/sakurabird/6868765