# Unable to scroll LinearLayout which is placed in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I referred most of the questions in Stackoverflow related to this topic and successfully placed my Linear Layout in a ScrollView. But I can't scroll it. The outline of my Activity is-

[image]

Here is the XML code of ScrollView-

```
<ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutUP1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewUP1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/Chocolate"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text=" "
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="@color/Black"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewUP2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/Chocolate"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text="User ID : "
                            android:textColor="@color/White"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewUP4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/Chocolate"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text="Gender : "
                            android:textColor="@color/White"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewUP3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/Chocolate"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text="Your Groups"
                            android:textColor="@color/White"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <GridView
                            android:id="@+id/gridViewUP1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:numColumns="1"
                            android:padding="5dp" >
                        </GridView>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
```

As you can see there is a GridView in the last LinearLayout. This GridView was scrollable before adding ScrollView. After adding ScrollView the layout named 'linearLayoutUP1' cannot be scrolled. How can I make it scrollable vertically ?

Comment: Can you post your code. In order to seedependencies.

Comment: post your xml file too..

Comment: try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `ScrollView`

Comment: @Lal Now scroll bar is appearing, but still I can't scroll.

Comment: try hardcoding the height for the first LinearLayout..ie change wrap_content to some 1000dp or so..just for testing..

Comment: and also what theme are you using???is it any fullscreen theme???

Comment: also check if there is `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for your activity tag in manifr=est..if yes try after removing that...

Comment: @Lal Am using full screen theme. android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" is no where in manifest file.

Comment: ok...so i think you are using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` ..try changing that to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` ..ie without fullscreen...try it..

Comment: @Lal Am not having a single Activity in my app. Every Activity is full screen. So when I made the change as you said now, I got error.

Comment: you are changing the theme right???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61853/discussion-between-manu-jacob-and-lal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hardcoding the height for the first LinearLayout..ie change `wrap_content` to some 1000dp or so. This will make it scrollable. I'm not at all sure whether this is the right way to solve the problem..But was telling you what I did when I faced the same situation.

Also, if you are using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` ..try changing that to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` ..ie without fullscreen...

Again,  check if there is `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for your activity tag in manifest..if yes try after removing that.

These are the solutions which i tried and worked when i faced a similar situatuion.

android activity always start scrolled to the bottom-to solve this problem please add  `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to your `LinearLayout`..

Answer (score 2):

I think nesting scrollable views in Android is considered bad design, and may not work properly. GridViews are inherently scrollable.

If you want to keep it, try looking here: [Problems with GridView inside ScrollView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264951/problems-with-gridview-inside-scrollview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to you any kind of scrollable view inside a ScrollView.

You may want to check this out in your case and see if it works.

http://lubosplavucha.com/java/2014/05/05/gridview-scrollview-issue/

Comment: How should I edit my code to make it working ? I extends Activity to my class and in the example you provided GridView is extended to that class.