# How to scroll two gridview and an imageview inside scrollview together

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I am having 2 gridview and an imageview inside scrollview, I want to scroll these views together.

The first gridview have only 4 items and second gridview is having more than 4 items.

So is it possible to scroll together.

my layout is,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_small"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/next"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/prev" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2" >
        </GridView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1"
            android:src="@drawable/ads" >
        </ImageView>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv" >
        </GridView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with GridView inside ScrollView in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264951/problems-with-gridview-inside-scrollview-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good practise to put one Scrollable view another.
As `GridView` is already scrollable.

If you want to do that you can refer below links

1. [Problems with GridView inside ScrollView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264951/problems-with-gridview-inside-scrollview-in-android)
2. [How to put GridView inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859250/how-to-put-gridview-inside-scrollview)