# How put Horizontal View and Gridview inside Vertical Scrollview

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I want to develop an app that includes GridView and I want it to be some thing like horizontal ListView above a gridvew .Horizontal view displays images downloaded from url.I saw this [touturial](http://topandroidphones1.blogspot.com/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html) ( horizontal scrollview used)

and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264951/problems-with-gridview-inside-scrollview-in-android) to put the GridView inside scrollView because i want to put the gridview(episode #2) and horizontal view (episode #1) in vertical scrollview(episode #3) . I need to scroll the horizontal view vertically when a user is scrolling the gridview and not to have fixed position at the top of the screen.

I have no idea how to do  this (use `horizontal ScrollView` or `horizontal Listview`)?

[image]

after vertical scrolling I want it to be like this (horizontal view must get scrolled vertically):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom interaction, so you probably will not be able to use a "standard" tool for this. You may want something like the `FloatingActionButton` (an example here: http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) but you also want it to scroll, so you may need to extend that class.

Also, you could use touch events to do a custom animation on the area, because you will need to track when it is displayed and the direction/distance of the motion event to collapse/expand it. You also would need to know anchors on the list, to determine when it should reappear...

This is a cool design concept, but usually "cool" = "difficult" because it's not standard.