# How to make whole page scrollable

Tags: android, scrollview, android-xml

I have a `activity` which has a `DrawerLayout`, `ImageView`, `TextView` and `GridView`. I want the whole page to scroll but only grid view ha scroll.

This is my xml.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- everything you already have -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/home_app_bar" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/picker1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/welcome"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/welcome"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Welcome,"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Guest"
                android:textColor="@color/accentColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/welcome"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/welcome"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/welcome" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:columnWidth="80dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Free Listing"
                android:id="@+id/buttonFreeListing"
                android:background="@color/primaryColorDark"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerCity"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name"
                android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar" />


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.techieweb.solutions.pickeronline.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not put `GridView` inside `ScrollView` simply because both have scrolling effect..

So if you want to have `GridView` inside `ScrollView` you have to do programatically like [Problems with GridView inside ScrollView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21264951/2553431) and [How to put GridView inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859250/2553431) posts..

You can have `TableLayout` in place of `GridView` and then put everything inside `ScrollView` like ..

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/rel"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          //-----// 
     <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          <TableRow
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          </TableRow>
     </TableLayout> 
     </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView> 
<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"   
//--//
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your Views in such a way that parent view is `ScrollView` and it has just one child View and the rest of your code is in this one child view. For example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <RelativeLayout>
        <!-- everything you already have -->
      </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You tried putting all of your code inside a scrollview?

Comment: Using a scrollview instead of DrawerLayout?

Comment: try using LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout as child of scrollview with orientation as vertical

Answer (score 0):

Make two childs inyour `DrawerLayout`

1. `ScrollView`
2. DrawerFragment

Inside `ScrollView` have `LinearLayout` with orientation **vertical** and put everything else inside the `LinearLayout`.

This will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this....

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/home_app_bar" />

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        // your other view
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/home_app_bar" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picker1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Welcome,"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Guest"
        android:textColor="@color/accentColor"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/welcome" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Free Listing"
        android:id="@+id/buttonFreeListing"
        android:background="@color/primaryColorDark"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerCity"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.techieweb.solutions.pickeronline.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```