# Height of child layout not matching parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a basic layout here, but the LinearLayout inside ScrollView is not matching the parent height.

```
<LinearLayout
    .
    .
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    .
    .>
    <EditText
    .
    ./>

    <Button
    .
    ./>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id = "@+id/layoutWeb"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:orientation = "vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id = "@+id/listWeb"
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "match_parent">

            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The ide suggests to change the linear layout's(id=layoutWeb) height to wrap_parent. I have selected the linear layout in the screenshot below, but its height is not matching the parent
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Never put ListView inside ScrollView, and does the first LinearLayout containe any padding ?

Comment: I just realized that was so stupid. But why wouldn't it work?

Comment: match_parent does not work in ScrollView root. Also you should newer put one scroll into another (ListView into ScrollView).

Comment: ListView inside ScrollView not match with parent layout height for that either you can use recycler view or refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264951/problems-with-gridview-inside-scrollview-in-android

Answer (score 4):

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutWeb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listWeb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**try this code . for listview you dont need to take scrollview. its already  scrollable**

Comment: Thanks. I got it now