# Gridview items autoresize issue?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

[image]

i using two expandable height grid view inside scroll view.i have facing this issue.when set dynamic texts in text view the grid view shows like below image.how to solve this issue?.when set static text in textview it view perfect.but using dynamic i got a issue.how can i fix it?

my layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/SIZE_5"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_sub_categories_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sub_categories_name"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:padding="@dimen/SIZE_5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:text="hello world"

        />


</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My java code :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private AQuery mAQuery;
    private TransparentProgressDialog mTransparentProgressDialog;
    private ExpandableHeightGridView mGridViewCategory, mGridViewProdcuts;
    private CustomTextView mTvNoData;
    private ArrayList<HomeSubCategoriesData> mArrayList;
    private ArrayList<HomeSubProductsData> mArrayProductsList;
    private String mSubCategoryGetDetails = "";
    private TextView mTvTitle, mTvBack, mTvProductTitle;
    private ScrollView mLinear;
    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_seller_sub_category, container, false);
        initialization(v);
        return v;
    }
    private void initialization(View v) {
       /* MainActivity dashboard = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        mainDashbordInterface = dashboard.mainDashbordInterface;
        mainDashbordInterface.setListener();*/
        mAQuery = new AQuery(getActivity());
        mTransparentProgressDialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_loader_image);
        mGridViewCategory = (ExpandableHeightGridView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_fragment_sub_category);
        mGridViewProdcuts = (ExpandableHeightGridView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_fragment_sub_products);
        mTvNoData = (CustomTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_data_grid_home_sub_seller);
        mTvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_sub_category_title);
        mTvProductTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_seller_sub_categories_product_title);
        mTvBack = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_sub_category_back);
        mLinear = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.linear_seller_sub_category);
        mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        mArrayProductsList = new ArrayList<>();

        mTransparentProgressDialog.show();
        mLinear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //auto fit column items in grid view
      /*  float scaleFactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 100;
        int number = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int columns = (int) ((float) number / (float)scaleFactor);
        mGridViewCategory.setNumColumns(columns);
        mGridViewProdcuts.setNumColumns(columns);*/
        getSubCategoriesData();
        mGridViewCategory.setExpanded(true);
        mGridViewProdcuts.setExpanded(true);
        //before change below line :  ajaxCallback.setTimeout(Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.ajax_timeout)));
        AbstractAjaxCallback.setTimeout(Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.ajax_timeout)));
        int newConfig = getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        mGridViewCategory.setNumColumns(newConfig == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 4 : 3);
        mGridViewProdcuts.setNumColumns(newConfig == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 4 : 3);
        mTvBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void getSubCategoriesData() {
        mSubCategoryGetDetails = getString(R.string.WS_HOST) + getString(R.string.WS_GET_CATEGORIES);
         //mSubCategoryGetDetails = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ckJkJopOdK?indent=2";
       // mSubCategoryGetDetails = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bSrFHjWEXS?indent=2";
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("order_id", getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));
        hashMap.put("seller_id", 266);
        hashMap.put("category_id", getArguments().getString("id"));
        Log.e("Categories list", "Hah map-->" + hashMap.toString());
        if (AvailableNetwork.isConnectingToInternet(getActivity())) {
            mAQuery./*progress(mTransparentProgressDialog).*/ajax(mSubCategoryGetDetails, hashMap, JSONObject.class, ajaxCallback);
        } else {
            //showAlert(getString(R.string.no_internt_connection), -1);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(MainActivity.coordinatorLayout, R.string.no_internt_connection, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //setUI(view);
                        }
                    });
            // Changing message text color
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
            // Changing action button text color
            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) sbView.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            sbView.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
            mTvNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    /*8SHow alert dialog box**/
    private void showAlert(String message, int flg) {
        AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        aBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        aBuilder.setMessage(message);
        aBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        aBuilder.create();
        aBuilder.show();
    }
/*8Web service Rrespoce**/
    AjaxCallback<JSONObject> ajaxCallback = new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject object, AjaxStatus status) {
            super.callback(url, object, status);
            Log.e("buyer order", "url" + url);
            Log.e("Buyer order", "Responce" + object);
            if (status.getCode() == 200) {
                if (object != null) {
                    if (url.equalsIgnoreCase(mSubCategoryGetDetails)) {
                        try {
                            if (object.getString("errorcode").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = object.getJSONObject("category");
                                JSONArray jsonArrayParent = jsonObject.getJSONArray("parentcategory");
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                mTvBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayParent.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject Object = jsonArrayParent.getJSONObject(i);
                                    mTvTitle.setText(Object.getString("name"));
                                    mTvProductTitle.setText(mTvTitle.getText().toString() + " Products");
                                    // mainDashbordInterface.setTitle(Object.getString("name"));
                                }
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("childcategory");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    HomeSubCategoriesData subCategoriesModel = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), HomeSubCategoriesData.class);
                                    mArrayList.add(subCategoriesModel);
                                }
                                JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("productdetails");
                                mTvProductTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                                    HomeSubProductsData subProductModel = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), HomeSubProductsData.class);
                                    mArrayProductsList.add(subProductModel);
                                }
                            } else if (object.getString("errorcode").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                showAlert("No order details found.", -1);
                            } else if (object.getString("errorcode").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        HorizontalSubCatAdapter adapter = new HorizontalSubCatAdapter(getActivity(), mArrayList);
                        mGridViewCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
                        HorizontalSubProductAdapter productAdapter = new HorizontalSubProductAdapter(getActivity(), mArrayProductsList);
                        mGridViewProdcuts.setAdapter(adapter);
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mTransparentProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                Log.e("progress bar", "Hah map-->" + "progress bar called");
                            }
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                } else {
                    mTvNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        mGridViewCategory.setNumColumns(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 4 : 3);
        mGridViewProdcuts.setNumColumns(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 4 : 3);
       /* float scaleFactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 100;
        int number = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int columns = (int) ((float) number / (float)scaleFactor);
        mGridViewCategory.setNumColumns(columns);
        mGridViewProdcuts.setNumColumns(columns);*/
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.tv_sub_category_back:
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                mTvBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

my Adapter class :

```
public class HorizontalSubCatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<HomeSubCategoriesData> mArrayList;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    public HorizontalSubCatAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<HomeSubCategoriesData> mArrayList) {
        this.mContext = activity;
        this.mArrayList = mArrayList;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mArrayList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mArrayList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_subcategories_list, parent,false);
            mViewHolder.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sub_categories_name);
            mViewHolder.mIvimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_sub_categories_img);
            mViewHolder.mIvimage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            mViewHolder.mIvimage.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            convertView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mArrayList.get(position).getCat_img()).resize(300,300).into(mViewHolder.mIvimage);
            mViewHolder.mTvName.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getName());
        /*String img = "http://app.joinerytrade.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/0/400_1_door_01.jpg";
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(img).into(mViewHolder.mIvimage);*/
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Toast.makeText(mContext, mArrayList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //calling fragment from adatper class...
                SubCategoryProductsFragment fragment = new SubCategoryProductsFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = ((MainActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("id", String.valueOf(mArrayList.get(position).getId()));
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView mTvName;
        ImageView mIvimage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use  android:layout_height="wrap_content" in your CardView?

Comment: it is because your text get two lines then every position shifted. try to set maxlines=1 in textview

Comment: yea there is different textview lenght... try to specific that.

Comment: but i want to use text view height is wrap_content.because textview text coming from json web service.so must i need to set wrap_content.what can i do?

Comment: post gridview code ..

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dashrowlin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dashImg"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dashName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:lines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: don't use lines.because my text values are from webservice.so it may be two or more then two.so i must use wrap_content

Comment: then try above layout and remove android:maxLines="2"
        android:lines="2"

Comment: also tried.my problem is can't Adjust the Height of the Row of the Gridview to Tallest View’s Height

Comment: post java code. i am using same type of layout with recycler view

Comment: you mean only adapter class or whole gridview & adapter class code?

Comment: if possible then both.

Comment: what is ExpandableHeightGridView? any external library?

Comment: custom gridview class.just check internet.it avialable

Comment: did you fixed height of ExpandableHeightGridView xml ?

Comment: then any additional property? where you get that class, any docs for that?

Comment: ExpandableHeightGridView. and post that main xml

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264951/problems-with-gridview-inside-scrollview-in-android

Comment: try to change value of android:stretchMode="columnWidth" in xml to height or something else

Comment: then i think you need to use other implementation

Comment: what implementation?

Comment: like, expandable listview/recyclerview