# ExpandableHeightGridView cuts last items android

Tags: android, gridview

I found the solution in SOF for using `gridview` with expanded height inside `scrollview` from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242001/expandable-height-gridview-inside-scrollview). But I have a problem when the `gridview` items are `dynamic`.My problem is,

> When the items are less, it works fine. If the number of items increases then the Gridview last row or some rows are not visible. And also I am getting some empty space above the first row.

This is my gridview,

```
 <com.example.xyz.myapp.ExpandableHeightGridView
        android:id="@+id/favor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        />
```

`Expandable height gridview` code is code is,

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (isExpanded()) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Can Anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you scroll the grid view?

Comment: I dont want to scroll it, and I have done `gridView.setEnabled(false);` .

Comment: In that case you have to set resize of view based on multiple device.use dimensions values for different screen size.

Comment: I couldn't understand. I just need a non-scrollable gridview to display inside scrollview. Could you please explain

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android. you should set the size of gridview or viewholder element based on various device

Comment: @sasikumar but why should I use it? I haven't defined any dimen values for gridview. I just used `wrap_content`